# Find color Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Im trying to create a function such that if you query this : 
`(color 'dress liste)` it should return `'blue`. assuming that listE is defined  for us  `(define liste '((hat . red) (dress . blue) (coat . yellow)))`

 
I think i'm close: here is what i have done:

```
  (define (color x List1)  

    (cond (((null? List1) '()))        

              ((equal? x (caar List1) (cdar List1)))        

              (else (color x (cdr List1)) ))
              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementing the `assoc` function. Your code only needed some correction of its parenthesis. Compare with:

```
(define (color x List1)  
  (cond ((null? List1) '())       
        ((equal? x (caar List1)) (cdar List1))
        (else (color x (cdr List1)))))
```